# Android Sqlite tow Rows as tow Columns, Pivots?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-1.5-cupcake

Came to know its called pivots, but couldn't get examples for sqlite without aggregation.

### Schema:

```
Readonly Table foos(_id, foo) (10 max records)
Readonly Table bars(_id, bar) (300 max records)
Readonly Table items(_id, foo_id, bar_id, item1, item2) (3000 max records)
```

### Output Required:

```
Select
 foos._id, 
 foos.foo, 
 bars.bar, 
 items.item1(bar_id=1), 
 items.item1(bar_id=2), 
 items.item2(bar_id=1)
```

i always need two columns.

Am i missing something very obvious. 
do i get a performance hit.
is my table design wrong, correct me!

### UPDATE:

```
SELECT
    foo_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE bar_id WHEN 1 THEN title ELSE NULL END) AS 'Item1',
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE bar_id WHEN 2 THEN title ELSE NULL END) AS 'Item2'
FROM 
    items
WHERE 
    foo_id=2
GROUP BY
    foo_id
```

this is what is ended up with.

Comment: is pivoting the columns to rows what you actually need?

Comment: isn't that what was my original question? is my table design wrong. correct me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [Common MySql Queries](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php), there are a lot of samples, including the pivots, which may help you.

You can find what you are looking for in [this section](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78).

Comment: thanks! for the link. and i have updated my question with the solution u came up with. please tell me if it can be improved for things like performance. thanks again!.